# What is the jQuery equivalent of the Prototype function .activate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototypejs, equivalent

Prototype's [activate](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/element/activate) function

> Gives focus to a form control and selects its contents if it is a text input

according to the Prototype website. i.e.

```
$('my_element_id').activate();
```

What is the equivalent function in jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#my_element_id').focus();
```

which is a shortcut for

```
$('#my_element_id').trigger('focus');
```

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: But this does not select the contents of the input field, does it?

Answer (score 4):

Prototype's activate() function focuses on and selects the entire contents of the elements of the form.

In JQuery, this behavior can be replicated with three functions:

```
// Focus
$('my_element_id').focus();

// Focus and select the content.
$('my_element_id').focus().select();

// Focus and select the content without problems in Google chrome
$('my_element_id').focus().select().mouseup(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('my_element_id').focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuerys `focus()` method does not select the text in the input field. Instead, add `select()`:

```
$('my_element_id').focus().select();
```